# Getting errors when importing project to my android project

Tags: java, android, import, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use google maps clustering in my project. I am using this one:

```
https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf
```

However I am getting issues when running my project. I was able to import it fine. But when I run the app, I see on the console:

```
[2013-08-24 18:44:42 - library] Could not find library.apk!
```

I think its not importing the clusterkraf project (which is called `library`) into my phone...

And when I try to run the code from this library in the phone, it throws an exception and crashes. Here is the log:

```
08-24 18:47:49.709: W/dalvikvm(4669): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41780360)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.twotoasters.clusterkraf.InputPoint
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at com.activity.idsconnect.ActivityMap.MakeMarkerArray(ActivityMap.java:159)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at com.activity.idsconnect.ActivityMap.onCreate(ActivityMap.java:112)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-24 18:47:49.719: E/AndroidRuntime(4669):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I kept in my project properties Order and Export:

[image]

I don't know how to properly include it in the app when exporting. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My project properties

[image]

Clusterkraf properties

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is android library you need to add it in little another way.

First go to properties of library project and go to Android tab. Make sure that 'is library' has been checked.

After that go to properties of your project and in Android tab add your library, then click apply.

Also library have android-support library. If you are going to run into problems with android support library then you will need to delete it from your project to just have 1 copy of these.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.
I added screen shots of my project and the clustering project properties.